# woocommerce - how to get detailed list of orders for a product

Tags: woocommerce, product, orders

This is a feature whose absence in WC shocks me. I need to be able to pick a product, and get a list of all customers who have purchased it! Seems like an obvious need, but I can't even find a plugin to do this.

In particular, we are selling admission tickets to an event, and we need to be able to print a list of names that can be used by people working the door- they need to see if a person is on the list.

I am a php guy and could learn to write a plugin, or simply add a hook to functions.php.

One solution might be to add a custom column to the orders page that shows the name of the product- then, you could sort on that column. That should be relatively easy, and would get the job done, albeit inefficiently.

If I could write a plugin that integrates into the product details pages and provides a purchase report, that would be nice.

What is a clean way to get this info?

Comment: Hi Lynn, if you have had any luck in achieving this, can you share it? I'm currently looking to do the same thing and have found absolutely nothing. It's lack of existence really does shock me too I have to say.

Answer (score 0):

This might be late but I am sure it would help someone. I encountered the very same requirement as OP and I wasn't able to find any solution. Thank GOD I know bit of coding so here is my workaround.

**Solution:** Considering that you are in the product loop i.e "content-single-product.php", this code will get you all the IDS of the orders for the current product. Once you get the IDs, you can play around with the orders easily.

```
       $orderIDs = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "orderids", true); 
       foreach($orderIDs as $IDs)
       {
           if(!empty($IDs)){
                   echo "<p>".$IDs."</p>";          
                   $orderInfo = new WC_Order( $IDs );           
                   echo "<p>".$orderInfo->billing_first_name."</p>";       
                   echo "<p>".$orderInfo->billing_email."</p>";            
           }
       }
```

**"billing_first_name"** and **"billing_email"** is a meta-key found in **"wp_usermeta"** table. You can put in different keys and get desired values as per your requirements.

***If you are outside the loop, you can define a Global post variable and get the ID of the product.***

This might not be a best option but at-least it is working. I hope someone else can improve the approach. 
Thank you.